# Error on prediction running keras multi_gpu_model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I've an issue running a Keras model on a Google Cloud Platform instance. 
The model is the following:

```
n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2], train_y.shape[1]

train_y = train_y.reshape((train_y.shape[0], train_y.shape[1], 1))

verbose, epochs, batch_size = 1, 1, 64  # low number of epochs just for testing purpose
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    m = Sequential()
    m.add(CuDNNLSTM(20, input_shape=(n_timesteps, n_features)))
    m.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    m.add(RepeatVector(n_outputs))
    m.add(CuDNNLSTM(20, return_sequences=True))
    m.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    m.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20)))
    m.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
    m.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))

self.model = multi_gpu_model(m, gpus=8)
self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

self.model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
```

As you can see from the code above, I run the model on machine with 8 GPUs (Nvidia Tesla K80). 
Train works well, without any errors. However, the prediction fails and returns the following error:

> W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1502] OP_REQUIRES failed at cudnn_rnn_ops.cc:1336 : Unknown: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
>   in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1285): 'cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor( tensor_desc.get(), data_type, sizeof(dims) / sizeof(dims[0]), dims, strides)'

Here the code to run the prediction:

```
self.model.predict(input_x)
```

What I've noticed is that if I remove the code for multi-GPU data parallelism, the code works well using a single GPU. 
To be more precise, if I comment this line, the code works without error

```
self.model = multi_gpu_model(m, gpus=8)
```

What am I missing?

**virtualenv information**

cudatoolkit        - 10.0.130 
cudnn              - 7.6.4 
keras              - 2.2.4 
keras-applications - 1.0.8 
keras-base         - 2.2.4 
keras-gpu          - 2.2.4 
python             - 3.6

**UPDATE**

```
train_x.shape = (1441, 288, 1)
train_y.shape = (1441, 288, 1)
input_x.shape = (1, 288, 1)
```

After Olivier Dehaene's reply I tried his suggestion and it worked. 
I tried to modify the input_x shape in order to obtain (8, 288, 1). 
In order to do that I also modified train_x and train_y shapes. 
Here a recap:

```
train_x.shape = (8065, 288, 1)
train_y.shape = (8065, 288, 1)
input_x.shape = (8, 288, 1)
```

But now I've the same error on the training phase, on this line:

```
self.model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
```

Comment: How do you load the trained model ?

Comment: The model is not saved and then loaded, but is stored in a class variable (self.model)

Comment: Is it possible for you to save the model as h5 file and then run the `predict` ?

Comment: Train and prediction are done in the same python process so no reason to save and load again the model i think...

Answer (score 3):

From the `tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model` we can see that it works in the following way:

> - **Divide the model's input(s) into multiple sub-batches.**
> - Apply a model copy on each sub-batch. Every model copy is executed on a dedicated GPU.
> - Concatenate the results (on CPU) into one big batch.

You are triggering an error because the input of the `CuDNNLSTM` layer is empty for at least one of the model copy. This is because the divide operations requires that: `input // n_gpus > 0`

Try this code out:

```
input_x = np.random.randn(8, n_timesteps, n_features)
model.predict(input_x)
```

Comment: yes with your suggestion works correctly! My original input_x.shape is (288,), how can i reshape it to use correctly?

Comment: I've updated my question with some details, please take a look a let me know